# RBAC in Yii, Guest not authorized

Tags: yii, rights, rbac

Im trying to implement RBAC in Yii (using the rights module).

When trying to authorize an unauthenticated user (Guest), `CWebUser` calls `CDbAuthManager`:

```
$access=Yii::app()->getAuthManager()->checkAccess($operation,$this->getId(),$params);
```

`CDbAuthManager` then tries to get the authassignments of the user

```
$assignments=$this->getAuthAssignments($userId);
```

The problem is, because the user is a Guest, `$userId` is `null`, and `$assignments` is an empty array. Therefore i can not i cannot authorize a guest user to any action (unless declaring allowedActions())

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: not entirely sure this is related but I strongly recommend avoiding Guest role checking. If its open to guest than it should be open to all then I typically lose the checkAccess() call. Why? See [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Guest is added to the defaultRoles in your config. Also make sure the Guest role has a bizRule which has the expression

> return Yii::app()->user->isGuest

Comment: `return Yii::app()->user->isGuest;`

Comment: Actually, implementing bizrule for Guest user, inheritance doesn't work. Ie Guest -> Authenticated. By removing the rule, and keeping Guest in defaultRoles, i get the result i want. I think :).